# scrape info from edline.net

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have searched the internet but have not been able to scrape from https://www.edline.net/InterstitialLogin.page due to the login process, If anyone could provide specific code for the website it would be helpful. I am also trying to scrape in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to do some [research](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) first, work on the code, and then ask question when you get stuck.

Since the login requires csrf, Selenium, which operate with browser is more straight forward. Here is a solution with python requests, I don't have an account so I can't test it.

```
import re
import requests

def get_csrf(page):
    matchme = r'name="csrfToken" value="(.*)" /'
    csrf = re.search(matchme, str(page))
    csrf = csrf.group(1)
    return csrf

def login():
    login_url = 'https://www.edline.net/InterstitialLogin.page'

    with requests.Session() as s:
        login_page = s.get(login_url)
        csrf = get_csrf(login_page.text)

        # username and password here
        username = 'user'
        password = 'pw'

        login = {'screenName': username,
                 'kclq': password,
                 'csrfToken': csrf,
                 'TCNK':'authenticationEntryComponent',
                 'submitEvent':'1',
                 'enterClicked':'true',
                 'ajaxSupported':'yes'}
        page = s.post(login_url, data=login)

        # if this print a page inside, it's working
        print page.text

login()
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but now I'm trying to access https://www.edline.net/UserDocList.page? and I did `r = s.get('https://www.edline.net/UserDocList.page?')
        print(r.content)` but it doesn't load the page, instead giving an error message. I suspect it know it's not a real person. Is there anything I could do differently?

Comment: @CameronBurrows error from the site or code ?

Answer (score 3):

I have found it helpful to use some of Firefox's plugins to identify what exactly needs to happen for webscraping.

You can use FF's Inspector feature (Tools -> Web Developer -> Inspector) to mouse over individual elements.

You can also get the Selenium IDE plugin for Firefox (get the one with the silver Se with a pencil -- not the multitude with the green puzzle piece icons.)  If you run it while you are navigating the site, you can see what the elements are.

On the `InterstitialLogin.page`, using Selenium IDE, I see the login elements are:

```
ID = screenName    <-- username
ID = klcq          <-- password
name = submitButton  <-- submit
```

If you are using the Selenium packages for Python, you can use a send_keys command, like:

```
userNameElement = driver.find_element_by_id('screenName')
userNameElement.send_keys('Cameron')
passWordElement = driver.find_element_by_id('klcq')
passWordElement.send_keys('Burrows')
submitButtonElement = driver.find_element_by_name('submitButton')
submitButtonElement.click()
```

Comment: so how would I implement this in python to log in?

Comment: The code above is how you'd log in. If you can edit your question to show what code you have so far, maybe I can be more specific.